# Regex to detect different type (length) of text in a closed bracket? Python

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to detect different information from closed brackets? Example:

Text = Hello World, this is my name **(Greta)**. For this example **(i need an example in a bracket)**

In my case I would like to only detect the brackets with more than one word inside using a regex.

> Output: I need an example in a bracket

Answer (score 0):

`\((\w+\s+\w+[^)]*)\)` is probably close to what you want.

- `\(` is an open-paren literal and `\)` is a close-paren literal
- `(...)` creates a capturing group, so we can get only the inside of the parens
- `\w` matches alphanumeric characters
- `+` says that we are looking for 1 or more of the specified character class
- `\s` matches whitespace characters.
- `[^)]` is the character group of anything other than a close-paren `)`
- `[^)]*` selects any number of non-`)` characters (including 0)
- `\)` matches the close paren.
- Taken together, we check for a `(`, then a alphanumeric word, then one or more spaces, then another alphanumeric word, then take as much as we need of things that aren't `)`, and then a close paren.

Note that this fails in cases like `Hello (Alice and (hello) Bob)`, where it will capture `Alice and (hello`. (This is a fundamental limitation to regexes, you will have to use another method if you need to parse nested parentheses)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
\(\s*[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z\s]+\))
```

Which will look for:

- `\(` : open parenthesis
- `\s*` : zero or more spaces
- `[A-Za-z]+` : followed by one or more letters
- `\s` : followed by a space
- `[A-Za-z\s]+` : followed by one or more letters and/or spaces
- `\)` : close parenthesis

#### Code:

```
import re

text='Hello World, this is my name (Greta). For this example (i need an example in a bracket)'

m = re.findall(r'(\(\s*[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z\s]+\))', text)

for match in m:
    print(match[1:-1])
```

#### Output:

```
i need an example in a bracket
```

Comment: Note that this will capture `( )`

Comment: Brackets have been removed in the `for-loop`